# Orchard CMS: Specify alternate for media field in content type

Tags: orchardcms

I have several content types with MediaLibraryPicker field. These fields contain PDF files from the media library.
I want to display these fields differently for different content types.
I can't create alternates in a regular way, because (as I can see) it's not possible to create alternates based on "parent's" content type. Shape Explorer also shows same names for alternates even in different "parent" types.
I tried to declare alternates in placement.info files but can't figure out how to specify it. I tried nesting content types:

```
    <Match ContentType="ParentType">
      ...
      <Match ContentType="Document">
        <Place Parts_Document_Summary="Content:after;Alternate=My_Alternate"/>
      </Match>
    </Match>
```

But it doesn't apply alternate. When I move inner `<Match ContentType="Document">` element outside of `<Match ContentType="ParentType">` element, it applies to both parent types as it should.

How is it possible to specify different alternates for documents in my case?
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create alternates for the field, not for the document part. From that alternate template, you can manipulate the shapes for the media items under the field, for example by adding them alternates, changing their display type, etc.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand!
I've come to the solution with creating alternates for the field, changing display type for displaying contents, and creating alternates for document part in placement.info with appropriate display type. Is it possible to specify alternate for document part right in field alternate?

Comment: The alternates you can use can be found in shape tracing. If you don't find what you need, you can add alternates from a shape table provider.